# doing something wrong with auto_html gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am trying to use the auto_html gem to convert a submitted youtube link into an embed link. I'm not getting any response from auto_html.  I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing?

In my Gemfile:

```
gem "auto_html"
```

I added :video_html column to my link model.  (here is the migration file)

```
class AddVideoHtmlToLink < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
add_column :links, :url_html, :string
  end
end
```

my scheema.rb looks like this:

```
  create_table "links", :force => true do |t|
t.integer  "user_id"
t.string   "url"
t.string   "title"
t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
t.string   "url_html"
```

end

my link.rb model looks like this:

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :admin
  has_many   :comments
  has_many   :votes

  validates :title, :url, :presence => true


  attr_accessible :title, :body, :url, :user_id, :url_html


  auto_html_for :url do
    html_escape
    image
    youtube(:width => 400, :height => 250)
    vimeo(:width => 400, :height => 250)
    link :target => "_blank", :rel => "nofollow"
    simple_format
  end
end
```

In my index.html.haml view, I've got:

```
%p
  = link_to link.title, link.url_html, :class => "youtube title_link"
```

Now when I submit this through the console:

```
Link.create(:title => 'test', :url => 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2LFVWBmoiw')
```

I just get exactly this returned and I don't get the :url converted into an embed code as in the example on the github page (https://github.com/dejan/auto_html)

Any idea what I'm missing?  Any help or pointers in the right direction are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing video_html as param, you should pass *video*. Try this in console:

```
Link.create(:title => 'test', :url => 'http://example.com', :video => 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2LFVWBmoiw')
```

Comment: thanks for your response! forgive my lack of understanding, but I tried that in the console and got this error:  ruby-1.9.2-p290 :033 > Link.create(:title => 'test', :url => 'http://example.com', :video => 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2LFVWBmoiw')
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: video

Comment: Ah! I've just checked your schema. You need video and video_html in your database. That's how it works. Video would be raw input from the user, video_html will be formatted markup to be shown on page.

Comment: Ok, so I edited the above to reflect my changes. Since I've already got :url in my database, can I use that instead of :video? In this case would it be auto_html_for :url do  as I've reflected in my edit?

Comment: No. There's a naming convection that you must have a pair: something and something_html.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I think I'm starting to get it now.  I used :url and then added :url_html to the links table. Does that output look correct?    => "<p><iframe width=\"400\" height=\"250\" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/a2LFVWBmoiw\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>"    Is it possible to get just the url without the html added to it (for example just http://www.youtube.com/embed/a2LFVWBmoiw)?

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't that what you start with - in :url?

Comment: I see there are filters, but where do you add them/edit them?

Comment: I just used url and url_html to store the links (to stick with the naming convention as you mentioned)